# 動画 (H.265)にも静止画(JPGやPNG)の場合のようなさらなる軽量化は可能なのでしょうか？

Tags: 動画

JPGやPNGは圧縮の仕方によって、
人目ではほぼ分からないレベルでの圧縮 (TinyPNG)などで、さらに数倍軽量化することが可能ですが、
動画もそういったさらなる軽量化は出来るのでしょうか？

H.265の動画をもっと軽量化したいと思っているのですが、
動画の場合は、コーデックの方式で圧縮率がほぼ確定する (ソフトウェアにはあまり寄らない)といった認識でよろしいでしょうか？

ちなみに、画質はソフトウェアによって変わりますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

> JPGやPNGは圧縮の仕方によって、人目ではほぼ分からないレベルでの圧縮 (TinyPNG)などで、さらに数倍軽量化することが可能ですが、動画もそういったさらなる軽量化は出来るのでしょうか？

技術的には可能です。

> H.265の動画をもっと軽量化したいと思っているのですが、動画の場合は、コーデックの方式で圧縮率がほぼ確定する (ソフトウェアにはあまり寄らない)といった認識でよろしいでしょうか？

いいえ。おなじH.265動画コーデックのエンコーダであっても、そのソフトウェア（＝エンコーダ）性能やパラメータ設定次第で "圧縮率" は大きく変化します。

> ちなみに、画質はソフトウェアによって変わりますでしょうか？

はい。むしろH.265などの動画コーデックは、JPEGやPNGなどの静止画コーデックよりもエンコーダ・ソフトウェア選定やパラメータ設定値による差異は大きくなります。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。
とてもわかり易かったです。

ちなみに、有料無料問わないのですが、
オススメのエンコードなどあれば、いくつか候補教えていただけますでしょうか？

できれば一括で複数の動画を軽量化できるものが良いです
(優先度的には、一括変換 > 圧縮率です)

Comment: 汎用性だけでいえば [FFmpeg](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) が色々なことを実現できますが、いかんせんコマンドラインツールなので玄人向けになります。一括変換したければバッチファイルから呼び出すことになります。操作性を重視するなら何らかのGUIツールを探した方がよいでしょうね。